# How to select all checkboxes by clicking on CheckBox column header of a DatagridCheckBox Column?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a datagrid with one checkbox column. If anyone clicks on checkbox present in the column header, all check boxes present in that particular column should be checked. How can it be achieved using XAML?

**Xaml:**

```
<DataGrid AlternationCount="2" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}"  Height="325" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,178,0,0" Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="733" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>                
                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                        <CheckBox Name="colCheckBox" Content="Select All" Width="70" Checked="colCheck_Checked" />
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>                            
                                <CheckBox Name="rowCheckBox"  HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>                           
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="ProjectId" Binding="{Binding ProjectId}" Width="200"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="BaselineStartDate" Binding="{Binding BaselineStartDate}" Width="200"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="BaselineEndDate" Binding="{Binding BaselineEndDate}" Width="200"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Actually you dont have to do it in xaml, just put the property boolean value to true

Comment: You should bind the property IsChecked of the checkbox in the column header to the property IsChecked of all checkboxes. This can be done in the code-behind, without having to do it in the XAML code, as pointed out by @Sajeetharan.

Answer (score 1):

Can you not just data bind the `IsChecked` property of the `CheckBox` in the `Header` straight to the `IsChecked` property of the `CheckBox`es in the rows? This should do the trick:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
        <CheckBox Name="colCheckBox" Content="Select All" Width="70" />
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Name="rowCheckBox" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, 
                ElementName=colCheckBox}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Of course, this would also allow users to uncheck all of the `Checkbox`es from any row and you might not want that. Alternatively, you could use data binding if you had a `bool` property in your item class:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding MasterIsChecked}" Content="Select All" />
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

And then update the items from the `MasterIsChecked` property in the view model (or code behind):

```
public bool MasterIsChecked
{
    get { return masterIsChecked; }
    set 
    {
        masterIsChecked = value; 
        NotifyPropertyChanged("MasterIsChecked");
        foreach (YourClass item in YourItems) item.IsChecked = masterIsChecked;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by ***this would also allow users to uncheck all of the Checkboxes from any row***? I'm not sure about the default `Mode` of the Binding here, but setting it explicitly to `OneWay` would prevent that from happening (if I understand what you mean correctly). However even with that added, the behavior is still not good. Such as when user unchecks a row, the header CheckBox should also be unchecked (because not all the rows are checked now). And if user checks all the rows manually, the header CheckBox should also be checked (because all the rows are now checked).