# Title and CheckBox in the headers in GridViewCheckBoxColumn telerik c#

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, telerik

I use telerik on c# wpf.

I have a GridViewCheckBoxColumn column in my table. I need the title of this column to contain CheckBox(which by default are to highlight the entire column) and name. Аnd so that the checkbox in the header marked all the elements of the table. How can I do it?

This is the expected outcome:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qwm1k.png

Comment: Maybe there is a built-in function?

Comment: C# and C are two _utterly_ different languages.  If you are posting a question about C#, please do not tag it as C.  Currently your question is barely visible to anybody who is remotely interested in C#.

Comment: Oh, accidentally happened, noted as c #. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use GridViewSelectColumn.

```
*`<telerik:GridViewSelectColum/>`*
```

Add to 'Header' property to this xaml code.
Good luck

Comment: Had tried. But i can’t make the title text and checkbox. If you there is an example, I will be grateful

Answer (score 0):

I'm Chuffed I can help you, ZakharovV

```
<telerik:RadGridView.Columns> 
   <telerik:GridViewSelectColumn>
       <telerik:GridViewSelectColumn.Header>
           <CheckBox>My Header</CheckBox>
       </telerik:GridViewSelectColumn.Header>
   </telerik:GridViewSelectColumn>
</telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
```

> "GridViewSelectColumn.Header" is important

Good Luck

Comment: The checkbox that we set does not work in automatic mode how GridViewSelectColumn should work. All the same, it will have to be processed in ViewModel.

Comment: look at 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24905315/how-to-select-all-checkboxes-by-clicking-on-checkbox-column-header-of-a-datagrid' this url